# Samsung Ace 2 with Cyanogenmod turns itself on when put on charger while turned off

Tags: cyanogenmod, charging, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

It started happenning after repair.
Could it be a software setting that was changed in repairshop or is it a hardware issue?
All they did was replace mini-USB port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the issue was in the non-original charger. I don't have original charger from Ace 2, but original charger from Galaxy S3 works perfectly fine, as well as charging from a PC via USB.

Comment: Okay, glad you figured it out.  For anyone who might come across this and the above solution doesn't solve the issue, another place to look in the settings is Settings->Display->Wake on plug ("turn the screen on when connecting or disconnecting a power source")

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of CM, check the **Settings->Developer options->Stay Awake** *(Screen will never sleep while charging)* option.

Comment: My question is not about screen turning on, but about the whole device turning on. Nevertheless, this setting was set to  ` off`, even the **Developer options** section was not  turned on (it is turned off by default, to turn it on you have to tap "Build number" seven times).